# Rails record attribute rendering as text, not as SVG

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A Rails 5 application has defined in   `/config/initializers/mime_types.rb`

```
Mime::Type.register "image/svg+xml", :svg
```

and routes contains a call to the svg

```
resources :markeradhocs do
  member do
    get   :svg,  format: :svg
  end
end
```

the controller action, states

```
def svg
  respond_to do |format|
    format.svg { render inline: svg}
  end
end
```

yet, a couple of snags are hit.

**1** - within a collection, `svg_markeradhoc_path(content.markeradhoc)`
the rendering is outright text

```
/markeradhocs/2/svg
```

and **2** calling the object via the controller action  `localhost:3000/markeradhocs/2/svg` returns an error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in MarkeradhocsController#svg
```

for the respond_to block of `svg` action.

How can the SVG render inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
def svg
  svg = 'svg here'
  respond_to do |format|
    format.svg { render inline: svg}
  end
end
```

Be sure to include the `xml namespace (xmlns)` in the `svg` tag, otherwise browsers just render the content as `XML`

And update

```
svg_markeradhoc_path(content.markeradhoc)
```

with

```
image_tag(svg_markeradhoc_path(content.markeradhoc, format: :svg))
```

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't explicit enough.  There's a controller action `svg` that has the SVG code and I am attempting to render it inline WITHOUT creating a file.

Comment: This generates the error described above: `ActionController::UnknownFormat` (yes XML namespaces are defined)

Comment: given the goal is to render the svg, this worked only when specifying  `image_tag(svg_markeradhoc_path(content.markeradhoc, format: :svg))`